# How to make JavaScript to be compatible with both client- and server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-side, server-side

I know how to make modules in NodeJS (it's rather simple). However, if I want to make something that is supposed to work in both server- and client-side environments, then would would one accomplish this?

Let's imagine you want to create a Model type ("class"). Let's say you have a class-creation function called `Lib.define()`. So, you write this:

```
Lib.Model = Lib.define({
    init: function() {
        // constructor...
    },

    save: function() {
        // saves the model.
    }
});
```

The above code would make Lib.Model an object which represents an instantiable type. However, how would you write it so that it's also NodeJS compliant? If you try to require the above file (`require('Model.js')`), it would not do anything since there is no assignment to `export`. If, however, I do that, then am I just supposed to have a useless `export` object in client-side environments?

Is there other ways to do this besides require that could just simply load and parse the JS and work globally so that the above code would produce `Model` member in the global variable `Lib`?

I am looking into [vm](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/vm.html) right now, but I am not sure how would I use it properly. I do have a file/class loader that resolves paths and loads scripts just like what Dojo does. Should I write some logic there that works as usual on client-side (places script tags), and for NodeJS, it would simply read the file contents and `vm.runInThisContext(code)`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSHint](http://jshint.com) just detects whether there's an `exports` symbol and adds to it if there is. Their check looks like this:

```
// Make JSHINT a Node module, if possible.
if (typeof exports == 'object' && exports)
    exports.JSHINT = JSHINT;
```

That checks to see if `exports` is an object and then checks that it's not `null` (via `&& exports`). Seems a reasonable approach, although of course it's specific to the [CommonJS module system](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) (which is what Node uses).

Comment: [underscore does a similar thing](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-10)